# Proper Procedure for combining Project branches to a demo branch

Tags: git, github, git-merge

The graph below constitutes the desired flow for how I want our development environment to proceed. There are 4 standard branches, ProdMaster, TestMaster, DevMaster, and master. Assuming the above four start out at the same baseline, three different developers could each create a new project or feature branch off of master. Once development is complete, each would merge their changes into DevMaster. Dev is mainly for demoing and testing, so let's say Project\Feature branch 2 gets approved to go to test while 1 and 3 do not. I want to be able to then take the Project Branch 2 and merge it into test without bringing over any of the changes that occured in Project Branches 1 and 3.

Originally we were using Merge Commits in GitHub, but what we noticed is that if Project Branch 1 got merged, then 2 and 3, the second branch would get the commits from the first branch and the third branch would get the commits from 2 and 3.

So we tried doing squash and merge, and that seemed to work as the new project\feature branchs would not get infected with separate commits from the base branch. This mostly seems to work, except one minor change will sometimes show all of the changes already made on the base branch. Sometimes this is due to conflicts, and if I fix the conflict in a single file the number of files changes goes from 130+ back to 1. Is it rebase I am supposed to be using? A mix of the two? Or am I just having an improper flow? I've researched quite a bit, as has other members of my team, and it's hard to see the practical difference between squash and rebase, even when graphed out.

[image: Git flow]

Comment: It would help if you outlined an example structure of your branches, and the desired structure. And also what are you rebasing onto what?

Comment: @battlmonstr We are rebasing from the Project\Feature branches into the TestMaster branch, also back into master.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible flow of development, and yes, you are looking for a rebase.

You could take the approved branch PB2, and rebase it onto the TestMaster (assuming here that both TestMaster and master are closely related).

You can optionally squash all the changes into a single commit.

Note 1: once the branches PB1, PB2, PB3 are merged into DevMaster, they are "soldered", and shouldn't be "unmerged". You can use DevMaster to test in bulk, but you should use the original branch PB2 for TestMaster if that is your unit of approval, or reject all 3 changes alltogether. Maybe that is why you have the confusion?

Note 2: in your description I don't see the difference between "master" and "TestMaster", because essentially both branches should contain approved changes ready for testing.

#### Alternative approach

You have 4 stages in the process:

1. developing in a feature branch
2. testing for approval on DevMaster
3. testing on TestMaster
4. waiting for release on ProdMaster

So instead of having fixed branches like DevMaster, TestMaster, ProdMaster you could have 3 sequences of branches indexed somehow. For example, if you work on version 55 of your product, you could have DevMaster55-1, DevMaster55-2, DevMaster55-3 (for each round of approval if there are several rounds), TestMaster55 for the testing of version 55, and ProdMaster55 (actual release of v55 that should go to production).

The benefit of this is that you don't have to keep those sequences in sync (e.g. TestMaster56 is going to be separate from TestMaster55), and the history of changes on each of those branches is very clean. In practice ProdMaster55 might be just a tag on the TestMaster55 branch, and TestMaster55 is a "stabilization" branch took off from master at some point, and accepting only fixes needed for v55.

Comment: TestMaster and master should almost always be the same. The only exception (and why we have two) is if a universal change that affects the entire application rather than the individual projects is changed. Then we push that change into master early to ensure everyone gets everything tested. I can say to your Note 1 that is what we are doing. Dev is one way.

Comment: The big question is why if I make a single change is it displaying 150 files changed when those files were already on the base branch? It sounds like you are saying I am doing everything right, and yet I still have this problem.

Comment: Since this question is mostly formulated in terms of git flow process, I can confirm that the process is sane. Feel free to pose another question about this particular issue and please add more example details there: describe the state of the 2 branches you have (which/how many commits, what files modified), and the commands you run in order to rebase/squash. Then people can help with that.

Comment: @battlemonstr I'm using GitHub for my rebaseing\merge\squash events.

Comment: I see. Still need more info to answer this.